# The authors of algebra books don't write this group $H'$ in their books. Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group.
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $N\nsubseteq H$.

Define a relation $\sim$ on $H$ as follows:
$a\sim b$ if and only if $a^{-1}b\in N$.
Then, this relation is an equivalence relation on $H$.

Let $\overline{a}:=\{x\in H\mid a\sim x\}$ for $a\in H$.
Let $H{'}:=\{\overline{a}\mid a\in H\}$.

Define a product on $H'$ as follows:
$\overline{a}\overline{b}:=\overline{ab}$.
Then, this product is well-defined:
If $a_1\sim a_2$ and $b_1\sim b_2$, then $(a_1b_1)^{-1}(a_2b_2)=b_{1}^{-1}a_{1}^{-1}a_2b_2\in b_1Nb_{1}^{-1}=N$.
So, $a_1b_1\sim a_2b_2$.

$H'$ is a group under this product:
Obviously, the associativity law holds.
$\overline{e}\in H{'}$ is the unit element of $H'$.
If $\overline{a}\in H{'}$, then $\overline{a^{-1}}\in H{'}$ since $a^{-1}\in H$.
And $\overline{a^{-1}}$ is the inverse of $\overline{a}$.

The authors of algebra books don't write this group $H{'}$ in their books.

Why?

Comment: Is that group just $H/(H\cap N)$? That group arises in one of the isomorphism theorems, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @D_S Yes. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question right, this group $H'$ that you mention is interesting to you, and you are wondering why this group is not used in algebra textbooks.

It actually *is* used.  Your $H'$ is nothing more than the quotient group $HN/N$, where $HN = \{ hn : h \in H, n \in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ as a normal subgroup.

As mentioned in the comments, another common expression of what you call $H'$ is the quotient group $H/(H \cap N)$.  The natural isomorphism between $HN/N$ and $H/(H \cap N)$ is the *second isomorphism theorem.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!